# iphone proxy connection

Tags: iphone, proxy, connection

i need use NSURLConnection throw proxy server, how I can do this, may be any body face this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to use CFURLConnection (the lower-level C style classes) instead of NSURLConnection to accomplish this, but some more information on what you're trying to do would be helpful.